# Correct (and best) collection type for listeners in Java

Tags: java, listener, observer-pattern, eventlistenerlist

I just want to introduce a small observer pattern (listeners) in one of my classes, and I want to use the best-practice approach.

My listener interface:

```
public interface ExpansionListener {
    void expanded();
    void collapsed();
}
```

Therefore, I want to keep a list of listeners

```
private List listener; // What kind of list should I take?
```

and two methods `addListener(ExpansionListener l)` and `removeListener(ExpansionListener l)`.

Now, my **question:** What kind of list should I take? I thought about using a concurrent list like [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), but I found out that also [EventListenerList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) exists. What is the best-practice approach for listener-lists in Java?

Comment: EventListenerList seems to be a good candidate

Comment: I'd use a `List<ExpansionListener>` for a start, if you only want to allow that kind of listener. Then I'd probably go with `CopyOnWriteArrayList` since changes to the listeners are probably quite infrequent but writes might occur in parallel by multiple threads (just assumptions about your architecture though).

Comment: A `Set` will be more appropriate to prevent an object from having multiple listeners of the same type.

Comment: @Sanjeev: I looked at the source code of `EventListenerList`, and it does not seem to be thread-safe (probably not a bad thing to look for). @Thomas: Also, not thread-safe. @Titus: Yes, a `Set` does not sound bad to get rid of multiple listener registrations. Is there some built in type specific for listeners, or just using the default concurrent one?

Comment: @Titus Since listeners are rarely required to have an identity beyond instance level, a `Set` would usually not confer any kind of advantage.

Comment: `List<ExpansionListener>` doesn't tell anything about thread-safety, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is meant to be thread-safe (JavaDoc says it's a "thread-safe variant of ArrayList").

Comment: `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is straightforward to use and when the list doesn't change much or doesn't grow big (as is the case with Swing listeners), its performance isn't an issue either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is thread safe.  Not all Swing components are thread safe.

Note: before Java 8, iterating over this collection would create garbage, however in Java 8 the `Iterator` can be placed on the stack with Escape Analysis.

```
final List<EventListener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

if (!listeners.contains(listener))
     listeners.add(listener);
```

Using a Set would be preferable esp as you might want to ignore duplicate registrations of a listener in a thread safe manner.

```
final Set<EventListener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

listeners.add(listener);
```

The performance will be much the same, though the `CopyOnWriteArraySet` has the advantage that the `add` is atomic, where as doing `contains` and then `add` is not atomic.

EDIT: As @Hulk suggests you could use CopyOnWriteArrayList.addIfAbsent, however this method is not available on List.

```
final CopyOnWriteArrayList<EventListener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

listeners.addIfAbsent(listener);
```

Comment: @Hulk it would be for `CopyOnWriteArrayList` though it is not available on `List`